# Ansible: continue play on a connection error to allow for different credentials

Tags: error-handling, ansible, connection-refused, remote-connection

I am basically trying this inside a role:

```yaml
---
- name: "Connection attempt 1"
  block:
    - name: "Credentials"
      set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ username_from_vault }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ password_from_vault }}"
    - name: "Try connection"
      ping:
  rescue:
    - name: "Other credentials"
      set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ other_username_from_vault }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ other_password_from_vault }}"
    - name: "Try connection again"
      ping:
```

The idea behind is a connection to machines which are either in state A or in state B. State A has a temporary user, state B the final user for ansible connections. The inventory comes from another source which must not care about additional variables entered by humans stating "well we are done with transition A->B", that is rather prone to errors.

Even with anything in the likes of `failed_when: false`, connections as such will always stop the play.

Is there a way to make ansible continue after a failed host connection? Or am I running in an entirely wrong direction? Mark that we want to test credentials here, so something like:

```yaml
    - name: "Try connection"
      delegate_to: "localhost"
      no_log: true
      shell: "sshpass -p {{ password_from_vault }} {{ user_from_vault }}@{{ inventory_name }}"
```

...may do technically the trick, but will offer an additional surface with a possible leak of the password during lifetime of the play, so that would be not-so-good practice I'd rather avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-unreachable-host-errors and the next chapter https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#resetting-unreachable-hosts should cover that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct comment by β.εηοιτ.βε (thanks mate!) points to [the Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-unreachable-host-errors) introducing `ignore_unreachable` since Ansible 2.7.

You can then catch the unreachability from a variable like:

```yaml
- name: "Connection attempt"
  ping:
  ignore_unreachable: true
  register: "conn"
- block:
  - name: "Change credentials"
    set_fact:
      ansible_ssh_user: "{{ whatever }}"
  - name: "Try the connection again"
    ping:
  when: "conn is mapping and conn.unreachable is defined and conn.unreachable"
```

There is still no "rescue wasy of things" in this answer and it will increase the unreachable count in the playbooks' summaries, but it works without the delegate_to-and-sshpass stunt.

And to use a different approach: The following "play" doesn't directly answer the initial question for unreachable events, but follows the philosophy of "try credential set #1, and on failure try credential set #2". wait_for_connection does not generate an "unreachable" event, and we can go for block-rescue again:

```yaml
- block:
  - name: "Connection attempt"
    wait_for_connection:
      timeout: 3
  rescue:
  - name: "Change credentials"
    set_fact:
      ansible_ssh_user: "{{ whatever }}"
  - name: "Connection attempt with different credentials"
    # Now truly generate "unreachable" if this fails, too
    ping:
```